# Recibir respuesta XML usando CURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

Tengo un código que retorna una respuesta de Amazon MarketPlace, es por get y obtengo las respuesta mediante cURL, si coloco la URL en el navegador me trae el xml, sin embargo si lo hago por php me trae el texto plano, aun no se mucho sobre cURL y quisiera ya sea traer el xml con las etiquetas o traer los datos más ordenados, (actualmente me trae todos los campos seguidos - inentendible) .

Así tengo mi código:

```
  $ch = curl_init($link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"))
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

   $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   echo('<p>' . $response. '</p>');
   print_r($info);
    ?>
```

Comment: Si, pero no funciona tampoco, aun así me sigue trayendo todo el texto plano, actualizaré la pregunta también con esa linea, gracias

Comment: Ah muchisimas gracias :D si quieres ponla como respuesta para darle el punto verde , mil gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos errores

**1.Debes Enviar en el header el `content-type`:**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml")
```

**2. Debes habilitar la transferencia de la respuesta:**

```
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
```

Esta libreria es muy usada puedes tener la documentacion en el [manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php)

tambien te invito a leer mas acerca de la libreria [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/) este sitio esta en ingles pero a final de cuenta todos los lenguajes de programacion ejecutan esta instruccion por debajo